# How to create a raised button function in dart and flutter?

Tags: function, flutter, dart

I am a flutter newbie and am struggling with creating a raised button function that takes two inputs (pushed route and text) and creates a raised button. Here's the raised button we have currently, and our app is going to have dozens of these, so we would like to make a function out of them to reduce code. I can't find this anywhere. Is this possible, if so what should we do.
Thanks!!!

```
RaisedButton(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 20,
    horizontal: 40,
  ),
  elevation: 20,
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstFloorNorth()),
    );
  },
  child: Text(
    'First Floor',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blue[800],
      fontSize: 30,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom raised button widget like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'first_floor_north.dart';

class CustomRaisedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final floorText;

  CustomRaisedButton({this.floorText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 20,
        horizontal: 40,
      ),
      elevation: 20,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstFloorNorth()),
        );
      },
      child: Text(
        floorText,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue[800],
          fontSize: 30,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, where you want to put your CustomRaisedButton you do this:

```
CustomRaisedButton(
  floorText: 'The name of the floor that you want.',
);
```

For your specific example, I mean:

```
CustomRaisedButton(
  floorText: 'First Floor',
);
```